# Show popup when update qty in mini cart using ajax magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, mini-cart

When I update qty in mini cart if qty is greater than the qty of products in stock, I want to show popup **"The requested quantity for ...(my product name) is not available."** using AJAX.

How to do that?

Thanks very much.